# Can't access api object properties - react Hooks

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, api, object

I've console.log'd the data being returned from my API and I get:

```
​
fetchedData: {…}
​​
confirmed: Object { value: 7650696, detail: "https://covid19.mathdro.id/api/confirmed" }
​​
deaths: Object { value: 425869, detail: "https://covid19.mathdro.id/api/deaths" }
​​
lastUpdate: "2020-06-13T04:33:11.000Z"
​​
recovered: Object { value: 3630249, detail: "https://covid19.mathdro.id/api/recovered" }
​​
<prototype>: Object { … }
​
<prototype>: Object { … }
```

Then, when I `console.log(data.confirmed)` I receive undefined, even though it's listed right there. I'm using hooks in my app, though I'm not sure that has anything to do with it because I'm able to console the data just fine. The problem is when I try to access the properties in data.

https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-banzai-2n2xq?file=/src/App.js

Comment: could you provide a screenshot of data console for clarity?

Comment: probably a lack of understanding of how asynchronous code works - but - no way of telling since you haven't shown any code

Comment: added sandbox link. currently it consoles data from the Card component

Comment: save ur files in codesandbox :)

Comment: files should be visible now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be

```
console.log(data.fetchedData && data.fetchedData.confirmed)
```

instead

```
console.log(data.confirmed)
```

Updated [`codesandbox`](https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-sutherland-xbd2d?file=/src/Cards.js)

EDIT:

Using [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), it should be like this.

```
let { fetchedData: {
  confirmed
} = {
    confirmed: 'defaullt value'
  }
} = data;
```

Comment: Thanks! This indeed shows the property I wanted to log. But how could I destructure this so I can access the value a little easier? ideally I want to do something like ({ data: {confirmed} }) in the params

Answer (score 1):

`setState` is asynchronous that's why `data` is still an empty object when `console.log` is executed. Here is a quote from the [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate):

> The setState function is used to update the state. It accepts a new
>   state value and **enqueues** a re-render of the component.

The reason you can see the whole object when you `console.log(data)` is that `console.log` may not evaluate the object values until you click the expand arrow.

`console.log` in different environments (browsers) may have different implementations.

If you want to see how `data` looks like at the moment after `setData({fetchedData});` is executed, you may log it this way:

```
console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data)));
```

For more about the "mystery" of `console.log`, please check [console.log() async or sync?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23392111/console-log-async-or-sync)

Answer (score 1):

You really don't wanna destructure there. But if you want, you can do something like this:
https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-blackburn-ywdzu?file=/src/App.js:177-667

```
 const [data, setData] = useState({});
  const [recovered, setRecovered] = useState({});
  const [confirmed, setConfirmed] = useState({});
  const [deaths, setdeaths] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      const fetchedData = await virusData();
      const { confirmed, recovered, deaths } = fetchedData;
      setData(fetchedData);
      setRecovered(confirmed);
      setConfirmed(recovered);
      setdeaths(deaths);
    }
    fetchData();
  }, []);
```